# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un sentencia sql sobre una tabla muchos a muchos donde esta cumpla mas de una condición?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo tres tablas:

- Artículos;
- Propiedades; y
- ArticulosPropiedades.

Esta última proviene de una relación muchos a muchos entre Artículos y Propiedades. Un artículo tiene muchas propiedades y viceversa.

Tengo que obtener registros de la tabla Artículos que tengan dos o más Propiedades, por ejemplo: Un teléfono que tenga 2GB de RAM, cámara de 12 MP y procesador QUAD CORE.

La sentencia que tengo ahora mismo es esta:

```
select * from `articulos` 
WHERE `articulos`.`id` in (
        select `articulo_id` 
        from `articulospropiedades` 
        where `articulospropiedades`.`Propiedad_id` = '9'
    ) and `articulos`.`id` in (
        select `articulo_id` 
        from `articulospropiedades` 
        where `articulospropiedades`.`Propiedad_id` = '11'
    ) and `articulos`.`id` in (
        select `articulo_id` 
        from `articulospropiedades` 
        where `articulospropiedades`.`Propiedad_id` = '18'
    );
```

Seguramente habrá una manera más óptima de realizar la sentencia SQL pero no doy con ella.

¿Se os ocurre una manera mejor de realizar esta sentencia SQL?

Comment: *Tengo que obtener registros de la tabla Artículos que tengan **dos o más** Propiedades*. Entonces no necesariamente esta limitado a las propiedades `9, 11, 18`?  La mayoría de las respuestas no parecen concordar con lo que estas diciendo. Puedes aclarar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No sé cómo de más eficiente sería, pero una opción sería seleccionar todos los articulospropiedades que tengan las 3 (agrupando y contando que su suma sea 3) y luego seleccionar solo los artículos que contengan ese ID:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articulos 
WHERE id IN (
             SELECT articulo_id 
             FROM articulospropiedades 
             WHERE propiedad_id IN ('9', '11', '18') 
             GROUP BY articulo_id 
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
            )
```

Comment: Más eficiente es porque con mi forma cada vez que vas añadiendo condiciones es una nueva subselect que tiene que procesar, si tienes dos no pasa nada pero si tienes veinte...

Answer (score 2):

Si me limito a lo que dices:

> Tengo que obtener registros de la tabla Artículos que tengan dos o más Propiedades

Entonces la sentencia sería:

```
select a.*
  from articulos a
 where a.articulo_id in (select p.articulo_id
                           from articulospropiedades p
                          group by p.articulo_id
                          having count(*) >= 2)
```

Otra opcion que vale la pena probar, de repente funcione mas rapido, usando `exists`:

```
select a.*
  from articulos a
 where exists(select null
                from articulospropiedades p
               where p.articulo_id = a.articulo_id
               having count(*) >= 2)
```

Comment: Me he explicado mal, lo siento. Que tengan valores específicos, pueden ser 2, 3, 4, n valores. Lo que si probaré es lo de exists(), creo que es mas eficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría con varios join:

```
select a.* from `articulos` a
join `articulospropiedades` p1 using (id)
join `articulospropiedades` p2 using (id)
join `articulospropiedades` p3 using (id)
where p1.`Propiedad_id` = '9'
and  p2.`Propiedad_id` = '11'
and  p3.`Propiedad_id` = '18';
```

Comment: Haré pruebas a ver cual es más rápida y lo pondré. La respuesta de Álvaro Montoro me parece más limpia pero lo que se busca aquí es eficiencia ;). Cuando hay hecho pruebas pondré a ver cual me ha dado mejor resultado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

La podrías optimizar de este modo

```
select * from articulos WHERE articulos.id in (select articulo_id from articulospropiedades where articulospropiedades.Propiedad_id in( '9','11', '18' );
```

En lugar de hacer tres consultas anidadas, puedes poner en una sola consulta la condición, para que el id este en los número que quieras

Comment: El problema es que si hago lo que tu me dices me devuelve los registros que tengan la propiedad 9 o 11 o 18, yo necesito que me devuelva los que tengan 9, 11 y 18.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
art.*
FROM
articulos as art
JOIN
(
    SELECT
    a.articulo_id,
    count(*) as cantidades
    FROM
    articulos as a
    JOIN articulospropiedades  as ap ON ap.articulo_id = a.articulo_id
    GROUP BY
    a.articulo_id
) AS cant ON cant.cantidades > 2 AND cant.articulo_id = art.id
```

En la consulta interna cuento las cantidades de caracteristicas que posee un articulo luego le hago JOIN con de nuevo con artículos y filtrando solo los articulos que posean más de dos características.